# Why is this Relation not Symmetric?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Given is a relation on bitstrings:

$$R = \{(b,b') | ((b = b') \lor (b = 0b')) \}$$

$0b'$ means the concatenation of $0$ with $b'$.

Is this relation symmetric?

In my opinion it is. If $b = b'$ is true, then $b' = b$ is also true, right? And since it's an OR it doesn't matter that $b = 0b'$ is not the same as $b' = 0b$, right? Because the truth table for OR is:

$$\begin{array}  
\\1\quad 1 \quad=\quad 1 \\ 
1\quad 0\quad =\quad 1  \\
0\quad 1\quad =\quad 1  \\
0\quad 0\quad =\quad 0\end{array}$$

But the solution manual says its not symmetric. Could somebody explain that to me please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

$\langle 01,1\rangle\in R$, but $\langle 1,01\rangle\notin R$, so it's not symmetric. The *or* means that you have *two* cases to deal with, and you do have to deal with both of them.

Comment: Ah, so both need to be true? But why is the relation reflexive since b = 0b is false right? While in the solution manual is says that the relation is reflexive.

Comment: @user: No, $\langle a,b\rangle\in R$ and $\langle b,a\rangle\in R$ need to be _either both true or both false_ for symmetry to hold. The relation is reflexive because $\langle a,a\rangle\in R$ for all $a$. It doesn't matter for this that $R$ also contains _other_ elements than those of the form $\langle a,a\rangle$.

Comment: @user3302735: Symmetry says that whenever $\langle a,b\rangle\in R$, then $\langle b,a\rangle$ has to be in $R$ as well. If you find one example of a pair $\langle a,b\rangle\in R$ for which the reversed pair $\langle b,a\rangle$ is **not** in $R$, you’ve shown that $R$ is not symmetric. Reflexivity just says that $\langle a,a\rangle\in R$ for each $a$ in the underlying set. As Henning says, reflexivity doesn’t say anything about pairs $\langle a,b\rangle$ with $a\ne b$: none of them needs to be in $R$, but any of them can be without affecting reflexivity of $R$ in any way.

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks: we caught it in time!

Comment: My pleasure, Brian.